# Was Ireland really England's first colony?

Tags: england, ireland, scotland, colony, wales

I have a vaguely decent knowledge of Irish history, but I know relatively little of the history of England.

I've often heard Ireland spoken of as England's first colony, but surely that 'title' would have gone to Scotland and/or Wales?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Neither Scotland nor Wales were [colonized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization) by England.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - ...As England did not move settlers in to capture and control the land?  I had been under the impression that Wales and Scotland were junior partners of 'Britain', but I recognise that that might have been through treaty or otherwise, not colonisation - I'll look it up. Thank you for your Welcome and instruction, I'll try to do that in future - just had this question running through my head today and thought I'd ask.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace For Scotland that may be true, but not for [Wales:1277-83  Colonisation and castle building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquest_of_Wales_by_Edward_I_of_England#Colonisation_and_castle_building)

Comment: (+1) I find it strange that this question has be closed because it '**promote or discredit** a specific idea'. Lack of research yes, but not for the given reason.

Comment: Didn't the Angles and Saxons start by colonizing **England**?

Answer (score 5):

**BBC**

According to the British Broadcasting Company Pope Adrian IV's Papal Bull in 1155 led the way to England's first colony.

[BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/history/empire/episodes/episode_02.shtml)

> The first proper colonisation took place not in the West or East Indies, nor in America, but in Ireland. Ireland was the first English colony. In 1155, Pope Adrian IV published a Papal Bull Laudabiliter giving Henry II authority over Ireland. The document's value was that it authorized invasion.

**1177**

Though it took until 1177 before it could be considered a colony.

> 1177 John Lackland, Henry II's youngest son was given the title lord of Ireland. The burdensome history of the British and their first colony was under way.